# Unable to recreate test project for importing WFS polygones

Tags: javascript, openlayers, polygon

I am unable to recreate the example project for automaticly importing the WFS polygones from a web service. I found this example project on the website of Openlayers:
[Openlayers Example Project](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html)

In this project they used a URL in the vectorSource variable. This is the link to the WFS service. I added a few console.log statements to check what the contents are of the links and some variables. [Here is a direct link to the codesandbox test project that works.](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vector-wfs-7thkt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I'n my test project i just changed the URL of the vectorSource variable to the WFS service i intend to use. But this does not work for in my case. I also updated the center variable coordinates of the view at the bottom to a location within my polygones. [Here is a direct link to my version of the codesandbox project.](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vector-wfs-z059c?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I also added the two javascript files at here if people don't wanne use the codesandbox projects and just wanne view the code.

**The working project from openlayers:**

```
import "ol/ol.css";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import GeoJSON from "ol/format/GeoJSON";
import { Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer } from "ol/layer";
import { bbox as bboxStrategy } from "ol/loadingstrategy";
import BingMaps from "ol/source/BingMaps";
import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector";
import { Stroke, Style } from "ol/style";

var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  url: function(extent) {
    var text =
      "https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&" +
      "version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=osm:water_areas&" +
      "outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&" +
      "bbox=" +
      extent.join(",") +
      ",EPSG:3857";

    console.log(text);
    return text;
  },
  strategy: bboxStrategy
});

console.log(vectorSource);

var vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)",
      width: 2
    })
  })
});

console.log(vector);

var raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new BingMaps({
    imagerySet: "Aerial",
    key: "BING KEY"
  })
});

var map = new Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: document.getElementById("map"),
  view: new View({
    center: [-8908887.277395891, 5381918.072437216],
    maxZoom: 19,
    zoom: 12
  })
});
```

***the source code of my attempt***

```
import "ol/ol.css";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import GeoJSON from "ol/format/GeoJSON";
import { Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer } from "ol/layer";
import { bbox as bboxStrategy } from "ol/loadingstrategy";
import BingMaps from "ol/source/BingMaps";
import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector";
import { Stroke, Style } from "ol/style";

var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  url: function(extent) {
    var text =
      "https://geoservices.landbouwvlaanderen.be/PUBLIC/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typename=PUBLIC:LBGEBRPERC2019&srsname=EPSG:3857&outputFormat=application/json&count=1000&bbox=" +
      extent.join(",") +
      ",EPSG:3857";
    console.log(text);
    return text;
  },
  strategy: bboxStrategy
});

console.log(vectorSource);

var vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)",
      width: 2
    })
  })
});

var raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new BingMaps({
    imagerySet: "Aerial",
    key: "BING KEY"
  })
});

console.log(raster);

var map = new Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: document.getElementById("map"),
  view: new View({
    center: [589973.4805179046, 6575521.818939352],
    maxZoom: 19,
    zoom: 15
  })
});
```

Comment: The error you are getting suggests the geoservices url you are using doesn't support CORS https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqEOR.png  You may need to use a proxy

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you have some documentation on how to set up a proxy in Javascript?

Comment: https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the URL din't support CORS. To fix this i created a Node proxy server: [Follow the link for instructions.](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9)